# How to remove one column of a calculated item in Pivot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have two columns. One with data from this year and the other with data from previous year. I now have added a calculated item in Pivot to display the % delta of these two years. Now when doing this Pivot will add 1 calculated item with two columns: one (of the previous year which is the base item) is blank and you will see the delta values in the second column. All this is fine - just how do I get rid of the blank column? I can hide it but then I will lose the heading. I can try to minimize the width of that column and the heading will for some reason carry over to the second column. This is ok but I have many of these deltas.

Can you please help?

Thanks very much in advance,
T.

Answer (score 0):

If this field is in the Pivot Table then it is also in the Field List,  which means you can uncheck the box beside the Field name in the field list, that should hide it.